# Searchbar in MAUI doesn't fire the SearchCommand if the text is empty in iOS

Tags: maui

In my `ContentPage` I have a `SearchBar` component. The `ContentPage` has a viewmodel that provides the `Command`.

```
<SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" BackgroundColor="white"
        SearchCommand="{Binding FilterCommand}"
        SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}"
        Placeholder="Filter" />
```

In Windows and Android, when the user types a word and then *Enter* the application, as expected, calls the `FilterCommand` and the text of the `SearchBar` as parameter. If the user remove the text and press *Enter*, the app calls `FilterCommand` and the parameter is empty. Everything is working as I expected.

In iOS, the behaviour is different. When the user types a word and then *Enter*, the application calls `FilterCommand` with the text as a parameter. In the following screenshot you see the filter in action.

Screenshot of the page without filter.

[image]

Screenshot of the page with filter.

[image]

Now, if I remove the filter using the key delete or tap on the `x` at the end of the `SearchBar` or tap `Cancel`, the `FilterCommand` is not fired. I can press *Enter* but it doesn't fired.

Is there a specific command to invoke when the user clicks on one of this elements?

Comment: The FilterCommand will not fire when enter is pressed if the field is empty both for  ios and android.  But for windows, the command will be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce that Android fires the FilterCommand when the Cancel is pressed. If the field is empty it shouldn't fire anything. Anyway. If you do want to take care of empty string and cancel I suggest MAUI ToolKit [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior)
It is a very useful way to handle events in your ViewModel. It can look like this:

```xml
<SearchBar
    BackgroundColor="white"
    Placeholder="Filter"
    SearchCommand="{Binding FilterCommand}"
    SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference self}, Path=Text}">
    <SearchBar.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            Command = "{Binding TextChangedCommand}"
            EventArgsConverter="{converters:TextChangedEventArgsConverter}"
            EventName="TextChanged" />
    </SearchBar.Behaviors>
</SearchBar>
```

You need to make a converter that takes care of SearchBar string value from the event

```cs
public class TextChangedEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var eventArgs = value as TextChangedEventArgs;
        return eventArgs?.NewTextValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And for sake of completeness a Command in the ViewModel

```cs
[RelayCommand]
private async Task TextChanged(string newText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newText))
    {
        await Toast.Make("Searchbar is empty!").Show();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Using  ```EventToCommandBehavior``` is an excellent idea! But why you add a ```EventArgsConverter```? It seems using a ```CommandParameter``` which binds to the text in the searchbar is ok in the behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, of course you can use `CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}"`. The reason for using a converter is that with that can make more checks and things if you want to manipulate the text before sending it to the command. But if you only need to send what is in the searchbar you can go with the CommandParameter. I am not the one doing it the simplest way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a control that searchs when the user writes on the control and also searchs when the text clears here is the code.
Just make a control that extends the searchbar and continue using it as normal.
Also i've implemented the SearchCommandParameterProperty so you don't have to specify the text value as parameter as it's redundant.

```cs
public class SmartSearchBar : SearchBar
{
    public SmartSearchBar() : base()
    {
        var bnd = new Binding(nameof(this.Text), source: this);
        this.SetBinding(SmartSearchBar.SearchCommandParameterProperty, bnd);
    }
    
    protected override void OnTextChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        if (this.SearchCommand?.CanExecute(newValue) == true)
            this.SearchCommand?.Execute(newValue);
        base.OnTextChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```